# php auto generate page from template

Tags: php, file, templates

I am working on a project where i want to save a modify and save a template in a name which is based on a user filled form. I found a way to save a file ,but i want to use a template and modify the value in that template based on the user filled form

```
<?php
    $name='kavin';
    $fh = fopen($name + ".html", 'w') or die("Could not create the file.");
    fwrite($fh, $text) or die("Could not write to the file.");
    fclose($fh);
    echo "File " . $name . ".html created!";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a template, use **{username}** as placeholder for the value in the template.

```
$name = 'kavin';
$template = file_get_contents('path/to/my/template.php');
$template = str_replace('{username}', $name, $template);

file_put_contents($name . '.html', $template);
```